# Remove the navigation bar from the home screen.

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have the main home screen in my app, which contains the app logo, sign up and log in button. When i press log in it should show a new page which provides different logging options through twitter, facebook, google. But i should also be able to get back, just in case I haven't signed up yet. When i Embed the main ViewConroller with a navigation controller, I have an unnecessary navigation bar even in the home screen. Is there anyway to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than remove it entirely, my guess is that you just want to hide it?

Perhaps try something like this:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Function that does that:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == true, animated: true)
```

Comment: tried this ;;; self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden=true  , but it disappears from the sign up page as well.

Comment: well set it visible on other screens like for example in viewWillDissapear set it up true ..

Comment: i think the viewDidLoad() on the SignUp page is the right spot to add it.